# How do I change python pandas LaTeX output formatting?

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I'm trying to better format my pandas dataframe output.

I have a series, which I then convert to a dataframe and then output to LaTeX.

```
meal.to_frame().to_latex('meal.tex')
```

This yields:

```
 \begin{tabular}{lr}
 \toprule
 {} &  count \\
 \midrule
 Meal    &        \\
 Spam    &  11723 \\
 Eggs    &   5865 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
```

How can I change the `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` to be `\hline`.
And how can I get the name of the index name `model` to appear as a column header? The end result I'm looking for is:

```
 \begin{tabular}{lr}
 \hline
 Meal    &  count \\
 \hline
 Spam    &  11723 \\
 Eggs    &   5865 \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of `to_frame()` is a string, so you can replace the `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` with `\hline` by:

```
print(df.to_latex(index=False).replace('\\toprule', '\\hline').replace('\\midrule', '\\hline').replace('\\bottomrule','\\hline'))
```

(assumes `df` is your pandas dataframe)

Setting `index=False` will remove the odd `{}` in the header of your first example.

Answer (score 0):

You could try working with tabulate https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate.
I use it for my Python projects all the time. You have two different LaTeX styles. But it's output is just a string with the LaTeX code, so you could always use a custom function to replace some parts.

If that doesn't work, try something else than the to_frame method. You could get the data with `as_matrix()`, add your labels and go from there.

For really custom styling you would need to write a simple script to build your string together yourself.